# .NET - Polymorphism in Overloaded and Overridden methods

Tags: .net, vb.net

I come from a Java background.  Please have a look at the code below (example taken from a Java book I once read and the code converted into .NET):

```
Public Class Animal
    Public Overridable Sub Eat()
        MsgBox("Animal Eat no arguement")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Horse
    Inherits Animal
    Public Overrides Sub Eat()
        MsgBox("Horse Eat no arguement")
    End Sub
    Public Overloads Sub Eat(ByVal food As String)
        MsgBox("Horse Eat food arguement")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim a1 As New Animal
        Dim a2 As New Horse
        a1.Eat()
        a2.Eat() 
        a2.Eat("Fruit") 'line 5
    End Sub
End Class
```

I would expect line 5 of the form_load to produce a compile time error.  In Java the compiler would look at the reference and see that Animal does not have an Eat method that takes a String.  Why is there no compile error in .NET?

**Update**
There is an error in the code above.  As the answerer points out; a2 is a reference to and an instance of Horse.  Hence why line 5 does not cause a compile time error.  If a2 referenced an animal and created an instance of a horse then there would be a compile time error (consistent with Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `overload`ing `eat()` with a version that accepts a `string` arg in the `horse` class. That is entirely valid.

An `overload` is a method with the same name but different arguments. Your overloaded `eat(string)` is perfectly valid and works just fine when called on an object and reference of type `horse`.

You could not call it on an object or reference of type `animal`, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I realise it is valid in .NET.  However, in my Java textbook it says: "Compiler looks at the reference and sees that animal does not have an eat method that takes a string.  Compiler does not care that the actual object might be a horse at runtime".

Comment: The object is a horse but the reference is an animal.  In the Java textbook it says: "the reference type (not the object type) determines which overloaded method is invoked.  To summarise, which overridden version of the method to call is decided at runtime based on object type, but which overloaded version of the method to call is based on the reference type of the arguement passed at compile time".

Comment: No, the reference is a Horse, not an Animal. "Dim a2 As New Horse" makes it a Horse.

Comment: @Graymatter, thanks for pointing that out(+1).  I should have created the reference and the instance on separate lines i.e. Dim a1 As Animal a1=New Horse

Answer (score 2):

`a2` is a reference to a `Horse`. `Horse` has an `Eat` method that takes a `string`. Now if line 5 was referencing `a1`, that would result in a compiler error.